# sizeof derived class in virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, sizeof

While going through virtual base classes, i got to know that to avoid ambiguity and to save space we use virtual base classes. I checked this concept with simple program as shown below **in CodeBlocks**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    int a;
};

class B : public virtual A
{
public:
    int b;
};

class C : public virtual A
{
public:
    int c;
};

class D: public B, public C
{
public:
    int d;
};

int main()
{
    cout<<"sizeof(int) "<<sizeof(int)<<endl;
    cout<<"sizeof(A) "<<sizeof(A)<<endl;
    cout<<"sizeof(B) "<<sizeof(B)<<endl;
    cout<<"sizeof(C) "<<sizeof(C)<<endl;
    cout<<"sizeof(D) "<<sizeof(D)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

got output as:

```
sizeof(int) 4
sizeof(A)   4
sizeof(B)   12
sizeof(C)   12
sizeof(D)   24
```

i understood the logic behind the first 4 lines of output, but i can't understand why **sizeof(D)  24**,
it should be 4(int d) + 4(int c) + 4(int b) + 4(int a) + 4(because of some virtual base pointer) = 20. Here **'a' is inherited only once** because of virtual base classes and hence i should have get **20** as sizeof(D) but it is 24.

someone please analyse and help me...

Comment: "to save space we use virtual base classes" - really? Is that a reason for virtual bases these days? I would never have suggested *that*.

Comment: Virtual base classes aren't about saving space.  In any event, both `B` and `C` may each supply a distinct "virtual base pointer" since they both have virtual bases, and all classes that inherit from each of them will need to be able to consistently find that "virtual base pointer".    `D` inherits from both, so both inherits "virtual base pointers" - the one from the `B` and the one from the `C` (and presumably initialises them to be equivalent i.e. pointing to the same inherited `A`).

Comment: *4(because of some virtual base pointer)* - What makes you think only one is required? Both `B` and `C` would need indirection to access that sub-object.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting those values? Because it wasn't reproduced in [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/JUa7Vq), [OnlineGDB](https://onlinegdb.com/SJvJrne1w) and even in mine.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code size of B is 12 and size of C is 12 so D inherits everything from B and C so depending on compiler and C++ versions, most of them just go the size of D is B+C or namely 24. But not every compiler does the same, so we cannot make any conclusion unless we know your C++ version and compiler version and IDE makes a big difference too..